# Request Still Attaches Cookie After Deleting it From Both Client and Server Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to implement a quick Login-Logout solution.

**Login:**

- Sends a POST request with AJAX (Client-Side)
- NodeJS creates a cookie (Server-Side)
- Reloads the page with javascript (Client-Side)

Works fine

**Logout:**

- Sends a POST request with AJAX (Client-Side)
- NodeJS deletes the cookie (Server-Side)
- I make sure to delete the cookie on client side as well with JS (Client-Side)
- Reloades the page with JS (Client-Side)
- NodeJS still somehow receives the cookie from the `req` ???

So, when I reload the page after Logout operation, I'm still logged-in. Only after I force refresh or press "Logout" one extra time, I see that I'm indeed logged-out.

I tried many different approaches and methods of loading the page and deleting the cookie, but nothing seems to work.

**Javascript:**

```
$("#logout").click(function () {    
    var username = this.value;
    logout(username)
    var currentUrl = window.location.href; 
    window.location.assign(currentUrl); //I tried different methods of reloading the page
  });

// perform logout action
function logout(username) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/logout",
    data: JSON.stringify({ username: username }),
    success: function () {
      //just in case remove the cookie
      removeLoginCookie()
    },
    error: function () {
      removeLoginCookie()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
  });
}
```

**NodeJS:**

```
app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {

  try{
    res.clearCookie('userlogin', { path: '/' })
    res.send({ "status": "Logged out successfully!" })

  }catch(e){
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem, by setting a timeout before reloading the page, but I'm not a fan of this solution and I'm still curious on why was it happening, and what would be a better way to do this.

```
$("#login").click(function () {    
  var username = this.value;
  logout(username)
  setTimeout(()=>{
    var currentUrl = window.location.href; 
    window.location.assign(currentUrl);
  }, 500)
});
```